# Hosting DNS nameservers across multiple providers

Tags: domain-name-system

Say I have a domain foo.com. I registered foo.com at networksolutions *AND* use the free nameserver service by networksolutions. (In other words, both pimary/secondary nameservers at network solutions)

Would it provide any value to host my secondary nameserver at another provider, for example, amazon.com dns, if networksolutions is completely down? Or does it not matter, because network solutions is the party that provides the nameservers in the first place, and if they are down then there's no way to know about the secondary.

If Yes -- who is the party that actually stores/provides the primary and secondary name server? In my scenario, if network solutions is completely down, how do clients know about my secondary nameserver at amazon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, having network redundancy for secondary DNS servers is specifically recommended by [RFC 2182](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2182).

In particular, the benefits include:

1. Reliability in the event of an issue with your primary nameserver
2. Spreading the load to improve efficiency
3. Decreased resolution time
4. increased performance

**Edit** to address the follow-on question:

Your domain nameservers are stored and configured in the [root nameservers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server).  Here's an example.

First, we inquire against my resolver which are the root nameservers for the com domain.

```
$ dig -t ns com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -t ns com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46051
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 13, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;com.               IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
com.            13893   IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            13893   IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
```

Next, we chose one of those root nameservers and ask it, what are the nameservers it knows about for google.com domain:

```
$ dig -t ns google.com @a.gtld-servers.net.

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -t ns google.com @a.gtld-servers.net.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62374
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 206 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:503:a83e::2:30#53(2001:503:a83e::2:30)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 17 08:54:30 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 164
```

Comment: So who is the party that actually stores/provides the primary and secondary name server? In my scenario, if netsolutions is down, how to clients know how to get answers from my amazon nameserver?

Comment: name server information is held by the gTLD name servers (a.gtld-servers.net, b.gtld-servers.net, etc.). So they'll know who your name servers are, even if Network Solutions is down.

Answer (score 2):

This may interest you: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6058107

> (I work on Route 53).
>
> We've done a lot of experiments on this one and we've found that the
>   most common resolvers make 3 tries to 3 different servers by default.
>   At first those servers are picked at random, but over time the
>   resolvers usually "home in" on what the least-latent nameserver is.
>   Once they do, and have a good round-trip-time estimate for how long it
>   takes to respond, they stay using it. But they have a hair-trigger; if
>   the nameserver doesn't respond, they'll very quickly fall-back to
>   trying the other nameservers.
>
> In practice what that means is that up to two of your nameservers may
>   be completely unresponsive and the effects will be pretty negligible.
>   So if you're using multiple DNS providers and want to protect against
>   one going off-air; use no more than two nameservers from each
>   provider.
>
> That said, for all of the reasons above, and some more, the Route 53
>   SLA currently only applies if you use all four Route 53 nameservers.